# Return true if 10% of time has elapsed between two dates

Tags: java

im trying to work out how i would go about identifying when a certain amount of time(10%) has elapsed since the start date(auctionStart), comparing this with current date and end date(aEnd).

This is the code i have so far, but im quite a ways off figuring this out. Ive been trying to use JodaTime as well.

```
private Date auctionStart;
private Date aEnd;

public Boolean tenPercentElapsed(){
    SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String aucStartString = f.format(auctionStart);
    Date aucStart = f.parse(aucStartString);
    DateTime currentTime = new DateTime();
    DateTime startTime = new DateTime(aucStart);

    int m = Minutes.minutesBetween(startTime, currentTime).getMinutes(); 
    double minutes = (double)m;
    if(){
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Is there a reason for not using the `java.time` API?

Comment: Time can be expressed in milliseconds. Take the number of milliseconds between the start and end (the current question uses minutes; essentially the same). That is the total. Take 10% of that total. Take start - current in milliseconds. Compare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transform the following formula into code and you're done:

```
x = 100 * (current date - start date) / (end date - start date)
```

Here, `x` is the percentage completed.

Because you're computing the ratio of two time intervals, the *units* of the interval don't matter. So you could use dates, minutes, seconds, or even milliseconds in the interval. The last choice ties in well with the return value of `java.util.Date#getTime()`.

Finally if you're using Java 8 and above, then consider ditching Joda time for the new `java.time` library.